# Should UX.SE have its own blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At the time of writing, about 15 or so Stack Exchange network sites have [their own blogs](http://blogoverflow.com/)

Every now and then a comment comes up: *It would be good if UX.SE had its own blog!*

It *would* be a good place to cover some of the news, events and topics of the day that don't make it into the Q/A format of the core site.

Unsurprisingly quite a few people on here already run their own blogs - some of them very popular.

Would the community both ***like*** and *more importantly* ***use*** a dedicated UX.SE blog?

Because if the answer is an overwhelming yes, this might well get picked up by the Community Manager and acted on.

Comment: Please see [this blog entry](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow) for more information about the community blogs and the process for starting one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A UX blog would be a great way to increase awareness of UX.SE if we take the time to write insightful posts, perhaps based on interesting content that surfaces in the site through questions, as well as offering members an outlet to comment on industry developments without having to ask questions. It would require significant time investment from multiple people. We should poll for people who are willing to commit. Further, I think anyone who contributes should be a proven writer. The definition of proven writer can be scoped as "writes great, comprehensive, eloquent answers", which allows us to draw upon and perhaps approach members of the community who meet that requirement.

See [Blogoverflow's getting started tips](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/) for a list of things we need to do in order to start a blog:

1. Raise the idea on the child meta. A community blog needs the
   involvement of community members.
2. Define the scope and purpose of
   the blog. Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic?
   Is it about the industry around the topic? Keep in mind the audience
   of your community and their interests. Another generic blog about
    may not be all that interesting.
3. Recruit contributors. Who will
   write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going
   through the buffet line. Be realistic – don’t let your eyes be
   bigger than your stomach. Think seriously about if and how often you
   will be able to contribute a blog post, including research/prep
   time.
4. Plan a schedule. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think
   about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one
   post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and
    posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily,
   but I would say at least one post a week.